# python executes linux shell, returns only one line

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to execute a linux shell in python, for example:

```
import os
cmd='ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep'
p=os.popen(cmd)
print p.read()
```

the code works well in python2.7,but it doesn't work well in python2.4 or python2.6

the problem is: when the environment is 2.4 or 2.6,for each process in linux it only returns one line.

for exmaple:

this is what i want(and this is just what is returned in 2.7):

```
59996    17038 17033  0 14:08 pts/3    00:00:02 java -Xms64m -Xmx256m classpath=/home/admin/axxxX xxxx//xxxxxxxx ....

root     85751 85750  0 12:25 XXXXX    XXXXXXX  XXXXXXXX
```

but it actually returns like this(in 2.4 2.6):

```
59996    17038 17033  0 14:08 pts/3    00:00:02 java -Xms64m -Xmx256m classpath=/home/admin/ax\n

root     85751 85750  0 12:25 XXXXX    XXXXXXX  XXXXXXXX\n
```

that means it cut each item and then there is only one line for each item left,and it adds an `\n` for each item in the result, which is what i don't want to see

i have try other method like `subprocess.Popen` or  `commands.getstatusoutput(command)`, but the results are the same -- i get only get one line for each item(process)

Info:

1. if i execute the shell directly on the ssh of linux, the result is good
2. if i execute `ps -ef |grep java |grep -v grep >>1.txt`, make the result into txtFile,the result is also ok

the python script will be executed on so many machines,so it is not proper to update all the machines to python2.7 or newer version

I am a little bit worried because the deadline will come soon, and i need help.
Looking forward to your answers, thanks very much

Comment: In python2.7 also you will get it with '\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps` usually clips its output according to the terminal width but, because you are piping the output to `grep`, `ps` can not determine the width, and so it determines that from various things such as the terminal type, environment variables, or command line options such as `--cols`.

You might find that you get different results depending on how you execute your python script. In an interactive session you will most likely see that the output of the pipeline is clipped to your terminal width. If you run the script from the command line you will probably see the full output.

Are your tests for the different versions of python being run on the same machine, and in the same manner (interactive vs. command line)? I suspect that some inconsistency here might be causing the different output.

Fortunately you can tell `ps` to use unlimited width using the `-ww` command line option:

```
import os

cmd='ps -efww | grep java | grep -v grep'
p = os.popen(cmd)
print p.read()
```

With this you should receive the full `ps` output.

Although `subprocess.Popen()` should produce the same result (since `ps` is doing the clipping) you should use it instead of `os.popen()` - when used with `subprocess.communicate()` you can avoid possible deadlocks.

Comment: sorry.to press up,i need 15 fame point ,but i do not have T_T

Comment: That's OK. You should be able to accept the answer, perhaps there is some minimum time period.

Answer (score 3):

You're making an unwarranted assumption about the behavior of `read`. Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) (and especially its `communicate` method) to read the whole thing. It was introduced in 2.4.

Use the string `splitlines` method as necessary if you want individual lines.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation of `subprocess.Popen()`, but what is the unwarranted assumption?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#file.read says "Also note that when in non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given."

Comment: Yes, but it's not in non-blocking mode... and it is not actually the cause of the problem, `ps` is. The data read over the pipe is not truncated - the first line is clipped, but the second line is fine. Furthermore, this problem persists when using `subprocess.Popen()`.